# tsql - Self reference

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a CTE that returns the below records. How should i proceed with the new query so that all records with `GID = NULL` will get the previous last GID?

```
ID  GID     VALUE
1   1       Some Value
2   NULL    Some Value
3   2       Some Value
4   3       Some Value
5   NULL    Some Value
6   NULL    Some Value
```

Eg. Records with ID 5 and 6 will have GID = 3

Answer (score 3):

```
with C(ID, GID, VALUE) as
(
  select 1,   1,       'Some Value' union all
  select 2,   NULL,    'Some Value' union all
  select 3,   2,       'Some Value' union all
  select 4,   3,       'Some Value' union all
  select 5,   NULL,    'Some Value' union all
  select 6,   NULL,    'Some Value'
)

select C1.ID, 
       C3.GID,
       C1.VALUE
from C as C1
  cross apply
    (select top 1 C2.ID, C2.GID
     from C as C2
     where C2.ID <= C1.ID and
           C2.GID is not null
     order by C2.ID desc) as C3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH C(ID, GID, VALUE) as
(
  select 1,   1,       'Some Value' union all
  select 2,   NULL,    'Some Value' union all
  select 3,   2,       'Some Value' union all
  select 4,   3,       'Some Value' union all
  select 5,   NULL,    'Some Value' union all
  select 6,   NULL,    'Some Value'
)
select c.id, d.GID, c.value from c 
cross apply 
(select max(GID) GID from c d where c.id >= id) d
```

Comment: It's not obvious at all but I see it now. You probably should give yourself a downvote. :)